# getting caller phone number using Core Telephony framework

Tags: ios, iphone, core-telephony

Here, i want to block call when app is open, but problem is arrived when getting call information address is 0x0.

I retrieve caller info like that:

```
    NSDictionary *info = (NSDictionary*)userInfo;
    NSString *state=[info[@"kCTCallStatus"] stringValue];

    CTCall *call = (CTCall *)info[@"kCTCall"];
    NSString *caller = CTCallCopyAddress(NULL, call);
    NSLog(@"Phone Number: %@",caller);
      CTCallDisconnect(call);
```

responce is like:

> {status = 4, type = 0x1, subtype =
>   0x1, uuid = 0x16e2fe20 [**], address = 0x0, externalID = -1, start =
>   2.22507e-308, session start = 4.83562e+08, end = 2.22507e-308, audioToneRelay = 0, setupAudioInterruption = 1, deviceOriginatedEnd =
>   0}

Printing description of caller1:
nil

Comment: Is your device jailbroken?  Otherwise there is no way to access the calling number

Comment: @Paulw11 no, my device is not jailbroken. can i  block calls when my app is running ?

Comment: No, you can't block calls

Comment: Don't know whether or not that's the problem, but `kCTCallStatus` looks like a string constant. You however create a strong with the content `kCTCallStatus`. The same true for `kCTCall`.

Comment: And yes, you (thankfully) cannot block calls.